# Selenium CSS selector throwing OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException - what's wrong?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I am attempting to find a table cell using a CSS selector in Selenium. This is my selector:

```
//table[@id='prepaymentItemsDataGrid']//tr[@class='tablerowlight']/td[3]
```

The exception being thrown is:

```
Driver.FindElementByCssSelector("//table[@id='prepaymentItemsDataGrid']//tr[@class='tablerowlight']/td[3]") threw an exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException'
```

What is wrong with my selector? How do I know what Selenium is complaining about?

I have tried simplifying it to:

```
//table[@id='prepaymentItemsDataGrid']
```

which has no effect.

Does Selenium have a different method of executing CSS selectors and how can I check that the selector is valid before trying to run it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you have tried to use `FindElementByCssSelector()` but the *values* were of *XPath*. You can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- *CssSelector* :

  ```
  Driver.FindElementByCssSelector("table#prepaymentItemsDataGrid tr.tablerowlight > td:nth-of-type(3)");
  ```
- *XPath* :

  ```
  Driver.FindElementXPath("//table[@id='prepaymentItemsDataGrid']//tr[@class='tablerowlight']/td[3]");
  ```

Comment: Crikey. Thank you! That was a wood for the trees moment. Guess I forgot what ChroPath was outputting. D'oh!